# $(document).ready (How to stop .ready on page load and instead allow .ready only when a html link is clicked)

Tags: document-ready

I'm still learning, please help!

I am trying to apply a Modal Popup that appears only when a link is clicked instead of when the page loads. My Modal Popup does all work fine, but I want to turn off/prevent the Popup from appearing at all when the page loads and simply have it only invoke the Popup when my chosen link is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#popup-1").myModal({  
        // Functionality goes below this line
    });  
});
```

And this

```
    <div id="popup-1" class="myModal">
        <div class="window">
            <!-- Your popup content -->
            <div class="wrap demo-1">
                <div class="title">Some Text Here</p>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your email goes here" />
                    <input type="submit" class="closeModal send" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                <label class="deny closeModal">Some Text Here</label>
            </div>
            <div class="cta demo-1">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <p>Some Text Here</span></p>
            </div>
            <!-- / Your popup content -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a simple fix I can apply to solve this issue? I have spent countless hours going through existing posts and forums but almost each enquiry doesnt target the same specific question im trying to achieve based on my actual existing code.

My cose for the Link Click to activate

```
<a href="" src="#openmyModal-1">Newsletter</a>
```

your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for `myModal`? Which plugin? If you're not, then post your `myModal` code, please.

Comment: Thanks I think ive added the html now

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your modal opening code when a link is clicked instead of when the ready event is fired :

```
$('#modal-link').on('click', function() {
    $("#popup-1").myModal({  
        // Functionality goes below this line
    });
});
```

assuming the link opening your modal is :

```
<a href="#" id="modal-link">link</a>
```

Comment: it stopped the loading on page load but click link not working either

Comment: ive gotten it to work, stupid me i set a class filled with rules, and forgot all i had to do was leave it blank.